# How to stub\mock instance in case statement?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have one class method, which use another one class instance method:

```rb
class Foo
  def foo
    # a lot of code here, which return String instance
  end
end

class Bar
  class UnknownType < StandardError;end 

  def initialize(foo)
    self.foo = foo
  end 

  attr_reader :foo 

  def call
    # some code which use method foo
    foo
  end

  private

  def foo=(attr)
    @foo ||= case attr
               when Foo then attr.foo
               when String then attr
               else raise UnknownType, "Unknown type #{attr.class.name}"
             end
  end

end
```

And my test doesn't work, I try to sub methods:
- is_a
- kind_of?

```rb
let(:foo) { instance_double(Foo, foo: 'some text') }
let(:bar) { Bar.new(foo) }

subject { bar.call }

it 'make some business logic here' do
  expect { subject }.to be_truthy
end
```

But it raise error `UnknownType` becasue template is a `#<InstanceDouble(Foo) (anonymous)>`

not a `Foo`

Comment: If your method expects an actual instance of `Foo`, then maybe you should pass an instance of `Foo` instead of a test double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case statements use `===` for case equality purposes and in this case `Foo` is the receiver not the argument. e.g.

```
  case attr
    when Foo then attr.foo
  end
```

Compares `attr` to `Foo` as `Foo === attr` not the other way around.

So you could change your test to

```
it 'make some business logic here' do
  allow(Foo).to receive(:===).with(foo).and_return(true)
  expect { subject }.to be_truthy
end
```

This way when it evaluates your case statement it will follow the `when Foo` path because `Foo === attr` will be true due to the stubbing.

Answer (score 0):

`instance_double(Foo).class != Foo`. As you have seen this returns an InstanceDouble object which won't work for the purpose of your comparison.

I would replace your instance_double line with manual instantiation and stubbing:

```
let(:foo) do
  foo = Foo.new
  allow(foo).to receive(:foo).and_return "some text"
  foo
end
let(:bar) { Bar.new(foo) }
```

That way `foo.class == Foo` and it will work in your case statement properly.